# Swift 2 try catch instead of if let

Tags: swift2

I am struggling to convert my logic to Swift 2 from what worked OK in 1.2 and hope someone can enlighten me please?

This is Swift 1.2 that allowed me to either update a record or insert a new one...

```
 if let people: [People] = DataManager.getContext().executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as? [People] {

      // stuff here

        DataManager.saveManagedContext()
    }
    else if let person: People = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(entityNamePeople, inManagedObjectContext: DataManager.getContext()) as? People {

       // stuff here

        DataManager.saveManagedContext()
    }
```

But now in Swift 2 I have this which is I think the same as first if statement in 1.2 code and allows for update of record, but as no more if/else how do I action the insert section?

```
 do {

        let people:[People] = try DataManager.getContext().executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [People]

        // stuff here

        DataManager.saveManagedContext()

    } catch {

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use `if let` with `try`:

```
do {

    if let people = try DataManager.getContext().executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as? [People] {
        // stuff here
    } else if let person = try NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(entityNamePeople, inManagedObjectContext: DataManager.getContext()) as? People {
        // stuff here
    }

    DataManager.saveManagedContext()

} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

*Note: I didn't verify if your functions actually throw, I'm just answering about the `if else` question, so I've used `try` for both in my example but you have to check if it's correct.*

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.  This solves it in part but the else if generates the warning  No calls to throwing functions occur within 'try' expression??

Comment: Ah, yes, that was the point of my note in the answer: I didn't check if `DataManager.getContext().executeFetchRequest` and `NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName` actually *throw*, I just used your example code as a base. Just remove the `try` for the method(s) that don't throw.

Comment: Thanks!  This really has made me feel twitchy as feel totally lost going from app that was perfectly OK to loads of errors like this!  I now see the func that throws and that thats does not.  I'm trying to accept your answer but forum reports I dont have enough reputation....

Answer (score -1):

check this code, using guard / throws helps you better

```
    guard let people: [People] = DataManager.getContext().executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as? [People] else { throw MessageType.description }

        // stuff here

    DataManager.saveManagedContext()

   guard if let person: People = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(entityNamePeople, inManagedObjectContext: DataManager.getContext()) as? People { throw throw MessageType.description }

       // stuff here

    DataManager.saveManagedContext()
```